# Generating multiple lines to be compiled in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm working on a VGA school-project that I'll synthesize on a FPGA. I'm working with Xilinx and using Verilog as a HDL. The project says that I have to generate a fixed number of particles, display them on screen and, by using the keyboard, I'll have to control the environment for these particles (like the wind, gravity etc.).

I can generate one particle with a size of 1 pixel (size is not important) by using:

```
  wire p1 =(posx>=part1x[13:4] && posx<=(part1x[13:4]+1) && posy>=part1y[12:4] && posy<=(part1y[12:4]+1));
```

By using this:

```
wire p1 =(posx>=part1x[13:4] && posx<=(part1x[13:4]+1) && posy>=part1y[12:4] && posy<=(part1y[12:4]+1));
wire p2 =(posx>=part2x[13:4] && posx<=(part2x[13:4]+2) && posy>=part2y[12:4] && posy<=(part2y[12:4]+2));
wire p3 =(posx>=part3x[13:4] && posx<=(part3x[13:4]+3) && posy>=part3y[12:4] && posy<=(part3y[12:4]+3));
```

three particles will be created.

How can I, for instance, generate 100 (or more) particles without having to write 100 lines of code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a "for" loop to generate this. Here is a very simple example:

```
wire input[100];
wire output[100];
// ...
genvar i; 
generate 
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i = i+1)  begin
    assign output[i] = ~input[i];
  end  
endgenerate
```

In order to apply this to your case, you might need to switch from using `part1x`, `part2x` etc., to using one big "array" and calculate offsets to it based on `i`.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your time and help, mr. Lazarenko.

Comment: Follow up question: since I have 100 particles how do I write `assign red=(p1 || p2 || p3 || ... || border)?3'b111:3'b000;`

Comment: @AnandWu: Not sure if I understand you question correctly. Could you elaborate a bit more? Or even create a separate question? Thanks.

Comment: I've made some arrays and used generate to help me with the problem but now I don't know how can I write p[0] || p[1] || p[2] || p[3] || ... || p[100] (without writing the whole thing, just like above).

Comment: Ok, I'll try to be more specific. Each one of the particles (p[1], p[2] etc.) is an area on my screen. I have 2 variables (x and y) that go through each pixel on my screen. When the (x,y) pair is in the area defined by the particle, p[i] returns 1. If I have 2 particles and define unified_area=p[1]||p[2] then when the (x,y) pair is in the area of p1 or the area of p2 it returns true. If I have 1000 particles how am supposed to write assign unified_area=p[1] || p[2] || p[3] || ... || p[999] || p[1000]? Is there any way to do it using for and/or generate?

Comment: @AnandWu: You can simply use "or" operator on a bus. If you have `wire p[1000];`, for example, you can do `|p` to get 1 if any of the wires in `p` is 1, or 0 if all are 0.