# Verilog, logic OR-ing an entire array

Tags: arrays, input, verilog

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
parameter n=100;
reg array[0:n-1];
```

How would one get the logic-OR value of each and every bit in the array?
The resulted circuit must be combinatorial.

This is a follow up question from [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613214/generating-multiple-lines-to-be-compiled-verilog/)
(see discussion below the answer)

Comment: Tim's answer shows a packed array declaration. It's very helpful to know the difference between this and an unpacked array.

Comment: Ok, so a packed array is something like `reg [9:0] packed;` and an unpacked array is `reg unpacked [0:9];`. I got that but what are the differences between the two?

Comment: In short, `reg [9:0] packed;` will be accessed as a single value whereas `reg unpacked [9:0]` cannot. So `packed = 6;` is valid but `unpacked = 6;` is not. I should have noted that packed/unpacked are SystemVerilog terms but the concept is the same in Verilog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this meets your design requirements, but you might have a much easier time with a hundred bit bus `reg [n-1:0] array;` than by using an array of 1 bit wires. Verilog does not have the greatest syntax to support arrays. If you had a bus instead you could just do assign `result = |array;`

If you must use an array, than I might consider first turning it into a bus with a generate loop, and then doing the same:

```
parameter n=100;
reg array[0:n-1];
wire [n-1:0] dummywire;

genvar i; 
generate 
  for (i = 0; i < n; i = i+1)  begin
    assign dummywire[i] = array[i];
  end  
endgenerate  

assign result = |dummywire;
```

I'm not aware of a more elegant way to do this on arrays.